# Way to do a proper integration testing with firebase emulators with all services at same time

Tags: firebase, testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to test my firebase back-end involving firestore, auth, and functions. There are cloud functions on new user created or deleted and rest like apis all affecting firestore data.

**I want to run test like this.**

1. I will start firebase emulator (with no data) in a terminal.
2. Run test file. Following everything will be in a script, so no part is manual.
3. I will register new users. Those should trigger firebase functions lets say affecting `users` collection.
4. Test if the `users` collection is affected.
5. Then do a fake login with any created user say `Jake Williams`.
6. Call some rest api. Those api will again change firestore data. For these cloud functions `auth` received will be of `Jake Williams`
7. Test if those firestore data is affected.
8. Clean emulator data and run other tests.

I have gone through docs, yet these is unclear. Went through [github/quickStart-testing](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing), still no help. I see there are tutorial which test firestore rules and some test cloud functions separately.

Can I setup a test project to work like my above requirements?

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is.  You have a lot of things going on here, and I'm sure it's possible to do them.  If you have a specific task at hand and are stuck on it, I suggest reducing your question to showing what you have so far and explaining what doesn't work that way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Firebase guide confusing. There they mentioned `firebase emulators:exec "./my-test.sh"`, not sure `my-test.sh` is. Normally not seen `.sh` file in node.js testing workflow. After 2-3 days, found the proper solution to my own question.

**Here are some things you should know.**

1. **firebase emulators:exec**

`firebase emulators:exec  'npm run test'` command run your test files within firebase emulator. So when your test files are using firebase admin `import * as admin from "firebase-admin";` I think this firebase admin will be linked to that emulator instance being created. Running  `admin.auth().createUser(...)` in that test file, then user will be created on that emulator. This `createUser` will also trigger side effects in cloud functions. You just have to wait for `5 sec` before testing triggered functions effects.

2. **You need to init admin and firebase function test with your project id**

```
import functionTest from 'firebase-functions-test'
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const PROJECT_ID = "your project id"

const test = functionTest({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
});
admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
})
```

3. **If you want to clear emulator data and reinit app between each tests**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const PROJECT_ID = "your project id"

const deletingFirebaseDataUrl: string = `http://127.0.0.1:8080/emulator/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents`;
const deletingAuthDataUrl: string = `http://localhost:9099/emulator/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/accounts`;

async function initApps() {
    admin.initializeApp({
        projectId: PROJECT_ID,
    })
}

async function deleteAllDataAndApps() {
    admin.apps.forEach(app => app?.delete());
    await axios.delete(deletingFirebaseDataUrl) //
    await axios.delete(deletingAuthDataUrl)
    test.cleanup();
}

beforeEach(initApps)
afterEach(deleteAllDataAndApps)
```

Going through the docs, I did not find these things or they were not clear to me.

Comment: This is accepted by me only :O